# How to combine Noto Sans CJK SC and Noto Sans CJK TC

Tags: html, css, fonts

It's a really weird requirement, I was making a Hong Kong website. I need to support `simplified` and `traditional` Chinese on the same web page, and I also want it to be Google `Noto` font.

Google provide the version of `simplified` and `traditional` font like this.
[image]

My question is that, if I only set `Noto Sans CJK SC`, the part of the traditional text will be the default setting instead of `Noto` absolutely.

So, how do I figure it out?

Comment: CJK fonts should have both traditional and simplified characters included. It doesn't matter which one to be used

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy uhh... no? Traditional and Simplied are mutually exclusive glyphs. You could use a stylistic set variant but that makes a font literally 40+MB and completely useless, not to mention the USHORT glyph space restriction in OpenType fonts, which makes it not worth the effort to try making a unified font.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is detect your user's locale, and then load the font that that locale needs. Are they geographically in the Republic of China, where everything's simplified Chinese? Load the simplified Chinese font by swapping in a `<style>` that loads in a font supporting that typographical choice. Are they in Hong Kong/Taiwan where traditional Chinese characters are still in use? Load in the traditional Chinese instead.

And then in addition offer some kind of pulldown or button set that users can click to switch between traditional and simplified Chinese.

Both of these should ideally feed into, and read from, `localStorage` so that you can save their preference and then read it back in on subsequent visits.

Comment: Yeah, I did detect the `location`, but it's a special case. Our service is in Hong Kong, but we have many customers from China. Basically, they choose `simplified`  Chinese, but we send messages to all customers in traditional Chinese. Therefore, they may display `simplified` and `traditional` Chinese on the same page.

Comment: use an override class for elements that always need to be one or the other, like `.msg-lang { font-family: 'the one with traditional characters'; }` and then make sure to mark up your dialog appropriately? The most specific CSS rule wins so if you set a base font on `<body>` and the override as a class, the override will kick in regardless of what `<body>` specifies.